# inaccessible objects in a flexbox with overflow and maximum height defined

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div container like this:

```html
<div class="list__products">
    <div class="products">
        {{#each rows}}
            <a href="javascript:addToRow('{{id}}')" class="products__a" value="{{value}}" id="{{id}}">
                <img class="products__a-img" src="../../../../resources/media/products/{{id}}.webp">
                {{name}}
            </a>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
```

where with each loop I generate a list of a products with handle bars, and I make it a specific size and adjust other parameters with this css:

```css
.main__new .list__products{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 36vw;
}


.main__new .products{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    max-height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: space-around;
    margin: 1.5vh 0;
}
```

and what is the problem? well, when I have a lot of products, the first ones are outside the div box and cannot be seen, I tried to fix it by changing the position but I can't find a feasible way to do it, try to change the height and overflow parameters assigning them to the `list__products` container but that makes it impossible to scroll to see the buttons that are outside this size, is there any other way to do it?

Sample of images:

[image: flexbox first image here]
[image: flexbox second image here]

Comment: What template engine are you using?

Comment: im using handlebars

Comment: Right. Can you somehow take the generated structure and use it to create a minimal reproducible example?